# ¿Cómo se llama en español a la parte trasera de una camioneta tipo pickup?

Tags: modismos, español-neutral

¿Cómo se le llama a la parte trasera de una camioneta tipo pickup?

[image]

En Guatemala se le llama palangana, en alusión a este tipo de recipiente:

[image: Palangana]

Comment: Caja de carga, al menos en Argentina

Comment: Parece que la flecha la dibujaste andando en la palangana.

Comment: jajaja, así mismo es!!

Comment: ¡Y yo que asociaba "pickup" con "tocadiscos" (de vinilo) y no con camionetas!

Comment: En Canarias se le dice "**boquete**".

Comment: Efectivamente:  **pick-up = tocadiscos**  [https://es.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pick-up]

Comment: En Argentina le decimos _chata_ a la camioneta y a la parte de atrás, _parte de atrás_.

Comment: Yo he oído "cajón" y "remolque", aunque este último es más inexacto. Me sorprende que no lo haya dicho nadie, puesto que recuerda a los cajones que todos tenemos en casa.

Comment: De donde eres @FGSUZ? Recuerda que son modismos, probablemente nadie de tu región había respondido o comentado aquí antes.

Comment: @jachguate soy de Zaragoza, España. No lo mencioné porque, honestamente, estaba seguro de que todo el mundo utiliza ambas palabras. Al menos en España, todos tenemos cajones en casa, y "Remolque" es un elemento que todo el mundo conoce, y de hecho se estudia en el carnet de conducir.

Comment: Yo por _remolque_ entiendo una extensión, estilo un carretón. Por otro lado "cajón", lo entendería, aunque no recuerdo haberlo escuchado nunca en este caso.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yo de coches entiendo poco, pero según la Wikipedia en la entrada para [pickup](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pickup) pone:

> [...] tiene en su parte trasera una zona de carga descubierta (denominada **caja, batea, carrocería, platón, cama o palangana**), en la cual se pueden colocar objetos grandes.

Lo que no dice es cuál de las expresiones correspondería con un español neutro. Según el DRAE:

- "Caja" no tiene restricciones regionales.
- "Batea" tampoco, pero no tiene una acepción que encaje, salvo tal vez la de vagoneta.
- "Carrocería" tampoco, y técnicamente esa parte del vehículo es parte de la carrocería.
- "Platón" se usa en América Central, Colombia, Ecuador, México, Perú, República Dominicana y Venezuela.
- "Cama" se usa en Cuba según el diccionario de americanismos.
- "Palangana" se usa en Guatemala y Nicaragua.

Comment: «Batea» se emplea en México.

Answer (score 5):

Puedes decirle

- **[caja](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6dxYOPn)**

> **5.** f. Espacio destinado a la carga en un vehículo de transporte de mercancías.

aunque esta palabra no se refiera específicamente a la parte abierta de las camionetas, sino también a la de los camiones o al compartimiento cerrado de las furgonetas.

Como metáfora, creo que tu *palangana* funciona perfectamente. Otras similares son **plato**, **batea** y **cama**.

Answer (score 1):

En España es llamada maletero a la parte trasera de cualquier coche destinada a la carga.

Answer (score 1):

En Colombia se les llama camionetas utilitarias con "platón" o "bandeja". Estos nombres son muy populares en especial en lugares rurales, pues en la ciudad generalmente se les dice "pickup".

Comment: En Antioquia le decimos "volco" a esa parte de una camioneta

Answer (score 1):

En Bolivia le decimos carrocería, y cabina a la parte de adelante que tiene techo y donde va el conductor y pasajeros.